# Can the click handler be removed from links on all StackExchange sites?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Many browsers nowadays use the middle mouse click as a shortcut on "open link in new tab." I've noticed a trend in the past few years to use click handlers in links, which breaks this behavior.

On sites that use this sort of click handling (generally for analytics, I assume), when middle clicking a link, I now get a new tab with the desired page, and additionally the page loads in the original page as well, giving me two tabs of the same page.

Is there a particular reason for this behavior?

Comment: What links are you talking about? I've never noticed a problem middle clicking before.

Comment: I think I have read already a report about middle clicks behaving strangely, or differently. I don't remember where I saw that report, though.

Comment: My mistake. This seems to be a problem with Google Chrome. Attempting to middle-click the same links in different browsers results in the expected behavior.

The issue is very intermittent, but seems to happen consistently on sites that exhibit the problem. Since the frequency of incidents seems increasing, I assumed it to be an issue on the part of website maintainers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just picked a [random question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443234/why-using-snd-sync-in-a-queueuserworkitem-bad), using Firefox 3.0.1 and I am not seeing this behavior by clicking on the first link in the question. I also clicked on a question itself in SO and I do not see this.

Comment: @Popular: Yea I know.. :) At home I use 4, but corporate only has 3.0.1 on this image so it is what it is